# Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Tags: anchor, pda, anchor-test, seed, signer

i'm getting the error in the title mentioned above and none of the solutions online seem to fix my error. This is the error msg in its entirety:
`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

and the relevant slices of code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMargin<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"margin-account", main_account.key().as_ref(), authority.key.as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + size_of::<MarginAccount>()
    )]
    pub margin_account: AccountLoader<'info, MarginAccount>,
    pub main_account: AccountLoader<'info, MainAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

The seeds passed look correct to me

```
    async getMarginAccountPda(mainAccountPubkey: PublicKey, marginOwner: PublicKey): Promise<Pda> {
        const [address, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from('margin-account'), mainAccountPubkey.toBuffer(), marginOwner.toBuffer()],
            this.program.programId
        );
        return { address, bump };
    }
```

I don't think i need to add a .signers([]) to the below since authority is type Signer

```
        const marginAccountPda = await this.getMarginAccountPda(mainAccount, this.wallet.publicKey);
        const marginInfo = await this.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(marginAccount.publicKey);
        if (marginInfo) {
            throw Error('MarginAccount ' + marginAccount.publicKey.toBase58() + ' already exists!');
        }
        console.log("mainaccount, marginaccount, authority", mainAccount.toBase58(), marginAccount.publicKey.toBase58(), this.wallet.publicKey.toBase58())
        const sig = await this.program.methods.initializeMargin(marginAccountPda.bump).accounts({
            mainAccount: mainAccount,
            marginAccount: marginAccount.publicKey,
            authority: this.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        })
        .rpc();
```

Answer (score 2):

With the way you're currently defining `margin_account`'s seeds in your anchor program, your frontend derivation should be thus:

```
async getMarginAccountPda(mainAccountPubkey: PublicKey, marginOwner: PublicKey): Promise<Pda> {
    const [address, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("margin-account"), mainAccountPubkey.toBuffer(), marginOwner.toBuffer()],
        this.program.programId
    );
    return { address, bump };
}
```

The change is in how `margin_account` is handled in `FindProgramAddress`.